# How can I deploy to Azure without exposing source code?

Tags: azure

At my workplace, we have a local git repository.
We need to deploy to *Azure*, but we cannot expose our git repository.
Is there any solution to deploying binaries to *Azure* automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to azure, and in your web app resource in the overview tab you find a button named Get publish profile

[image]

You can then go to visual studio. On the top menu if you click on Build, the scroll down menu have an option named Publish <"Your project name">

There you load this file and you can deploy directly to your Azure App from your machine without exposing the source code.

If you want to automate your deployment you can use a [custom deployment script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script)

You could also find useful the microsoft documentation page on [Local Git deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git)

Comment: That's great, but it's a manual solution, I am looking for a continuous-delivery like solution.